# Rally App SDK 2.0: Filtering a store of Users by UserPermissions

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I am attempting to build a store that consists of only Users that are not disabled and have editor permissions on the selected Project. However, UserPermissions is an array of UserPermission objects, which makes such a filter rather complex. It seems that a UserPermission can be of the WorkspacePermission or the ProjectPermission type. So, it looks like I would first have to check the type of the UserPermission, and then check whether the _refObjectName contains the name of the selected Project and "Editor," OR, alternatively, delve deeper into the ProjectPermission itself and check the Project's name and the Role for "Editor" separately. I have attempted to use the filterBy function, passing in a function that takes a record and an id, but I am unable to hit the breakpoint I set inside that function, so I have no idea whether it is working. The results displayed in a combobox certainly do not seem to match what I am querying for. Any suggestions?

**Edit1**: I have tried modifying the query to scope to the particular project name, but I receive this error: "Could not parse: Attribute \"Project\" on type ProjectPermission is not allowed in query expressions." Is there any way to get around this?

Here is the modified query, excluding the actual project name:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/ProjectPermission.js?pagesize=1&fetch=true&includeSchema=true&includeMeta=true&query=%28%28Role%20=%20Editor%29%20AND%20%28Project.Name%20%3D%20%22**{PROJECT NAME HERE}**%22%29%29

**Edit2**: Just thought someone might want to know. I received this error when trying to add another parameter to the query to filter by a User's DisplayName.

"Could not parse: UserPermission does not support complex queries yet. You can only query by Role OR by User, not both."

**Edit3**: I am having additional trouble with a call to get all the Project Permissions for a User based on their DisplayName. The query, as far as I'm concerned, is formatted as it should be. However, only results for some users are returned, and I have no idea why other users aren't included. I have even tried modifying it to query on FirstName, and the permissions for the user are not included in the result set.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/ProjectPermission.js?pagesize=200&fetch=true&includeSchema=true&includeMeta=true&query=%28User.DisplayName%20%3D%20%22**{INSERT NAME HERE}**%22%29

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Permissions endpoint to make sure that the that permission is for an Editor you can see the json for that request by following this [link](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/ProjectPermission.js?pagesize=1&fetch=true&includeSchema=true&includeMeta=true&query=%28Role%20=%20Editor%29).

To get the list of Users that are active you query them with disabled = false like [this](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/users.js?pagesize=1&includeSchema=true&query=%28disabled%20=%20false%29).

Once you have Permission data in memory you can filter out the users do not that have Edit permissions and match them with the list of active users.

Comment: I am unable to see that example you linked. I do not believe my subscription allows me to view that demo page? I am not sure.

Comment: I need to try to filter it down to a single permission, such that it belongs to a particular project. Is there a way to modify the query to do this? I have provided my modified string in the original post.^